# gnome3 fallback mode applet programming, docs?

Tags: api, applet, gnome, gnome-3

Where can I find documentation for writing an "gnome3 fallback mode" applet? Google spits a lot of usless things at me.
And the main question: Does it use the gnome3 extensions API or something completly different?

Please no guesses, facts+links pawn :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to borschty from IRC: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeGoals/AppletsDbusMigration

Sorry for the invconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You should also read this  [GNOME Shell fallback panels](http://www.vuntz.net/journal/post/2011/04/13/gnome-panel-is-dead,-long-live-gnome-panel!)